# jQuery: getting the nth position of an object

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains checkboxes. I also have a function that accepts a jquery object parameter. It looks like this:

```
function analyze_checkbox(cb) { ... }
```

Given this, is there a straightforward way to know the child position of the **cb** parameter? I was thinking of something like this:

```
cb.parent().index(cb)
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Thanks,

Erwin

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If no argument is passed to the
> .index() method, the return value is
> an integer indicating the position of
> the first element within the jQuery
> object **relative to its sibling
> elements**.

So in  your case `cb.index();` should do it

Example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/qQzte/

and do not forget that the results is 0-based

Answer (score 1):

If your checkboxes really are siblings of each other, then Gaby's answer saying `cb.index()` should do it is quite correct. Be careful, though, that you understand what `index` is actually telling you. For example, with this markup:

```
<div id='thediv'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' value='1' name='one'>One</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' value='2' name='two'>Two</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' value='3' name='three'>Three</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' value='4' name='four'>Four</label>
</div>
```

...if your `cb` is from (say) `$('#thediv input[type=checkbox][name=three]')`, the result of `cb.index()` will be `0` ([link to example](http://jsbin.com/aruzo4/5)). Clearly not what you want.

You can handle that in a couple of ways. With the specific example above, you could just look to see where the parent `label` was relative to *its* siblings: `cb.parent().index()` ([link to example](http://jsbin.com/aruzo4/4)). But depending on your markup, that could be complicated.

There's a way that's less subceptible to subtle markup changes: Select **exactly** the list of elements you want to consider, and then ask jQuery where `cb` is within that list. So with the markup above, you might do this:

```
// The selector choose *exactly* the set of things we want to
// look at, and then `index` looks for `cb` within that list
var index = $('#thediv input[type=checkbox]').index(cb);
```

[link to example](http://jsbin.com/aruzo4/6)